# Confluent Kafka Streaming examples not working

Tags: java, maven, streaming, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I tried to run the kafka-streams examples at: https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/master/kafka-streams

Commands like `mvn compile` and `mvn test` on branch "kafka-0.10.0.0-cp-3.0.0" are supposed to "Work out of the box".

[image]

I get an error saying:

```
$ mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building foo-bar-baz-artifact 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:0.10.1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:jar:0.10.1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:jar:test:0.10.1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.941 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-13T17:31:33-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project foo-bar-baz-artifact: Could not resolve dependencies for project foo-bar-baz-group:foo-bar-baz-artifact:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:0.10.1.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:jar:0.10.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:0.10.1.0-SNAPSHOT in http://packages.confluent.io/maven/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of confluent has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Full issue [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/issues/44).

How do I get the Kafka streaming examples working?

Answer (score 3):

> Commands like mvn compile and mvn test on branch "kafka-0.10.0.0-cp-3.0.0" are supposed to "Work out of the box".

Yes, and they do -- there's a Travis CI setup configured for this branch that verifies the build on every commit.

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:0.10.1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

It looks like you didn't actually use the `kafka-0.10.0.0-cp-3.0.0` but simply run `mvn compile` on the `master` branch instead (which is the default branch).  Only the `master` branch uses Kafka version `0.10.1.0-SNAPSHOT` (which isn't released yet), and that's why -- as stated in the README -- you need to run additional steps if you use `master`.

Your workflow for using branch `kafka-0.10.0.0-cp-3.0.0` should have been:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/confluentinc/examples.git

# Switch to `kafka-0.10.0.0-cp-3.0.0` branch
$ git checkout kafka-0.10.0.0-cp-3.0.0

$ cd examples/kafka-streams
$ mvn compile
```

Note: If you did want to use `master`, the README contains instructions on how to build latest Kafka version `0.10.1.0-SNAPSHOT`.  Roger Hoover mentioned one of the steps, but the step-by-step instructions are at https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/master/kafka-streams#apache-kafka.

Btw, it looks like you also modified the code:

> [INFO] Building foo-bar-baz-artifact 1.0-SNAPSHOT

"foo-bar-baz" is not part of the code base.  So perhaps you need to revert those changes until you have the base build setup working for you.

EDIT: For what it's worth, I also changed the repository settings of https://github.com/confluentinc/examples to use `kafka-0.10.0.0-cp-3.0.0` as the new default branch (before: `master`) so that beginners do not run into the same problem as you did.  This means that, after running `git clone ...`, you do not need to also run `git checkout kafka-0.10.0.0-cp-3.0.0` anymore to switch to the working-out-of-the-box branch `kafka-0.10.0.0-cp-3.0.0`. Hope this helps!

Comment: @michael-lafayette Did this answer your question? If yes, feel free to accept and/or upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Before you can build the examples, you need to clone ["trunk" branch of Apache Kafka](https://github.com/apache/kafka), build and install it.

```
./gradlew installAll
```